# jQuery datatables: test if datatables plugin is initialized

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to check if a table element with say, id="datatable" is datatables-initialized. Something like this:

```
if ($('#datatable').dataTable().initialized) {
  alert("initialized!");
}
else {
      alert("not initialized!");
    }
```

How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "initialised"?

Comment: Lets say, i have several tables of the class="datatable". They are all datatables-initialized using: $('.datatable').dataTable(); Then i dynamically add another table with the class="datatable" which is _not_ datatables-intialized. Now i want to iterate through all the tables with the class="datatable" and do some stuff based on the condition - is *this* table element datatables-initialized or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, add a special class name when you're initializing datatables:

```
$('.datatable').not('.initialized').addClass('initialized').dataTable()
```

And now you can tell them apart by class name:

```
alert( $('#datatable').hasClass('initialized') )
```

Comment: Great idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

You can the fnIsDataTable function in jQuery datatable

```
var ex = document.getElementById('example');
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( ex ) ) {
  $(ex).dataTable();
}
```

You can find more information in [api](http://datatables.net/api)

Comment: seems this should be the canonical way for datatables > 1.9.1

Comment: I believe this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: should be marked as the right answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

I feel following is the right answer to this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery().dataTable) {
         // your code to do some detaul set ups 
    }
});
```

For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (jQuery().dataTable) {

            $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
                iDisplayLength : 200,
                aLengthMenu : [[100, 200, 300, -1], [100, 200, 300, "All"]],
            });
        }
});
```

By this way you `if(jQuery().<libname>)` should be able to check any library loaded or not.

Comment: This is a great approach to all jquery plugins.

Answer (score 3):

Datatable has a method to check if an element has been initialized as a datatable or not - **[$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable](https://datatables.net/reference/api/$.fn.dataTable.isDataTable%28%29)**

```
tableElement = document.getElementById('your table ID');
$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable(tableElement); // returns true or false
```

Answer (score 1):

After you've called .dataTable() does it do anything to the table that makes it identifiable? i.e. does it add a new class "initialised" or something like that? If so, you could just loop through the items like so:

```
$('.datatable').each(
    function(index, element) {
        var _table = $(element);
        if (_table.hasClass('initialised')) {
            // Do stuff
        } else {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
);
```

Apologies if this isn't what you mean. It's not clear in your question what "dataTable()" actually does.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replay. I forgot to mention its about the 'datatables' plugin for jquery, and yeah, i was asking myself the same question - how to identify the table which is datatables-initialized. I asked the question on the datatables forum and got what i wanted from Allan: http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=4180&page=1. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The method cite by frenzy is designed by the author of the DataTables plugin; it is a very fine solution IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `callback()` function to do the same in my scenario. Thought of sharing this as an alternate approach

```
/* During Initialization */
var isTableInitialized = false;
$('#datatable').dataTable({/* your dataTable configurations*/},initializeDT());

/* Implement a callback function to set the value */
function initializeDT() {
    isTableInitialized = true;
}
```

Later in code..

```
/* Checking for Initialization is easier*/
if(isTableInitialized) {
    /* Do something here */
} else {
    /* Do something here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery().dataTable) {
        $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            /*some default settings*/
        });
    }

    $('#myDataTable').DataTable();
});
```